# Is arduino alternative of analog circuit?

Tags: arduino

As you understand I am begginner. Wondering Arduino and analog circuit do the same thing. Are they classified in the same class? Whats pros and cons of arduino or analog circuit?

Comment: Depends on what you want to accomplish, please describe your application

Comment: which analog circuit are you talking about?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terms are not in the slightest related, at least not without any context.

Arduino is a family of hobbyist microcontroller boards for the purpose of doing quick & dirty embedded system programs without much in the way of programming knowledge. Often using legacy microcontrollers such as 8 bit AVR.

An analog circuit is a very broad term and could mean a whole lot of different things. Usually it is something that involves some manner of operational amplifiers. The application could be anything from power electronics to RF.